# Window.open is opening 2 equal windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html/jquery code, that is supposed to open a new page, but is opening 2:

```
$('.div_link').live('click', function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('url'), '_blank', 'toolbar=no,resizable=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes');
});

<div class="div_link" url="/test/as/8888888-888">8888888-888</div>
```

So, everything is working fine, except that I get two new windows with the exact same content in them.
 I've seen people suggesting that there was something to do with returning false in the onclick event, but I don't think it's the case here.

Also, I've tried to do something like:

```
var handler = window.open(...);
```

**Edit:**
Tried something alike what gdoron suggested but then it doesn't open any window, and the click event isn't fired.

```
$('div.div_link').on({
    click: function(){
        window.open($(this).attr('url'), '_blank','toolbar=no,resizable=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes');
        return false;
}});
```

Comment: Are you definite the function is not being called twice? Try adding a console.log before the window.open

Comment: +1 for Sam, comment out `window.open...` and add in `console.log("You've clicked this once");`

Comment: ok, i did what you suggested, and yes, the function is being called twice. what can I do to call it just once?

Answer (score 6):

What can cause this:

1. You subscribed twice.
2. You're clicking twice.
3. You have two nested divs with the class `div_link` and the event bubbles.

Regarding the last option, use `on` instead of the deprecated(1.7)-deleted (1.9) `live` function:

```
$('#containerId').on('click', '.div_link', function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('url'), '_blank', 'toolbar=no,resizable=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes');
    return false;
});
```

You can stop the bubbling in `on` unlike with `live`.

Comment: I did what was suggested above, and the function is being called twice. will changing live('click') to on solve it?

Comment: @elithin, why won't you try...?

Comment: well, the divs with class=div_link don't have a unique container that I could use the id to bind the event. It would require some major refactoring,  I think...

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem, I solved by giving the second parameter a fixed name instead of using _blank.
Meaning the following:

```
$('.div_link').live('click', function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('url'), 'myFixedName', 'toolbar=no,resizable=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes');
});
```

This solution does not prevent the double click but it gives the desire behavior.
I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that '_blank' at the second line. it solved my same exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes removing `_blank` and replacing it with common Name like website title where you want to redirect

Example:

```js
window.open('https://googole.com', 'Google webiste');
```