# React - open new tab once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If a component is rendered. I want to open a new tab. (`window.open(url, "_blank")?.focus();`)
But (during development) this tab is opened twice because of the React.StrictMode.
How can I prevent this from being called multiple times without disabling the StrictMode?

My Attempts:

```js
function MyComp() {
    useMemo(() => window.open(url, "_blank")?.focus(), []);
    return <div>...</div>;
}
```

(doesn't work (called twice))

```js
function MyComp() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const id = setTimeout(() => window.open(url, "_blank")?.focus(), 10);
        return () => clearTimeout(id);
    });
    return <div>...</div>;
}
```

(works, but seems not like a good solution)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window.open is opening 2 equal windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631512/window-open-is-opening-2-equal-windows)

Comment: Looks like you meant `useEffect` instead of `useMemo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to keep a track of whether you have already opened the new tab.

```js
function MyComp() {
    const openedNewTabRef = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!openedNewTabRef?.current) {
            window.open(url, "_blank")?.focus();
            openedNewTabRef.current = true;
        }
    }, []);

    return <div>...</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create this custom `useEffectOnce` hook in a separate file that will only execute code once, even during `StrictMode`:

```js
// ./src/hooks/useEffectOnce.tsx

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const useEffectOnce = (effect: () => void | (() => void)) => {
  const effectFn = useRef<() => void | (() => void)>(effect);
  const destroyFn = useRef<void | (() => void)>();
  const effectCalled = useRef(false);
  const rendered = useRef(false);
  const [, setVal] = useState<number>(0);

  if (effectCalled.current) {
    rendered.current = true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!effectCalled.current) {
      destroyFn.current = effectFn.current();
      effectCalled.current = true;
    }

    setVal(val => val + 1);

    return () => {
      if (!rendered.current) {
        return;
      }

      if (destroyFn.current) {
        destroyFn.current();
      }
    };
  }, []);
};
```

now instead of importing `useEffect` from React, import `useEffectOnce` from the directory you saved the hook in and do:

```js
import { useEffectOnce } from "../hook/useEffectOnce" // <-- the path where you saved the hook

[...]

    useEffectOnce(() => {
        const id = setTimeout(() => window.open(url, "_blank")?.focus(), 10);
        return () => clearTimeout(id);
    });
```